# HTML elements overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, css-position

So I'm using hero image for my website which is 100 vh high. Now the image is positioned absolutely, so I could position other elements like logo, nav and text on the image relatively to it. After this section, I want to start new section with new image and other text, but once I start new row, column and try to put new image with h1 text, it's hiding behind earlier image. What I mean is that I want a new section with new image and `<h1>` text appear under the hero image and not overlap it or hide under it as it is now hiding. It's not floated or anything, my floats are cleared, so I don't get it why is this hapenning.

Here is some codepen so  you would understand what is hapenning.

```
<div class="container-fluid clearfix">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero_img">
      <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.png"></img>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">
☰
</button>
      <div class="collapse">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul class="nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="black_box clearfix"><h1>Kolding Bike Marathon</h1></div>
    <div class="black_box_sub clearfix"><p>Bring activity to your life again</p></div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Register now</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Learn more</button>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

      <div class="section_one">
      <h1>heyyyyy</h1>
    </div>



.hero_img {
  background-image: url("assets/hero.jpg");
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}



.hero_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1002;
  width: 5%;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
  padding: 20px;
  /*float: right;*/
  width: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #555;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  filter: opacity(0.93);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

a:hover {
  color: #999;
}

.nav-item {
  display: block;

}

.navbar-toggler {
  /*float: right;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}

.black_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  clear: both;

}

.black_box h1 {
  color: white;
  /*font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;

}

.black_box_sub {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1001;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 2%;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.black_box_sub p {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/NpbwYp

Comment: i didn't get what you are asking, can you elaborate a bit more? maybe with a picture and what it's like now and what you exactly want

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the "vh" measurement but I suspect this might have something to do with your problem. You are setting your image to 100% of the vertical viewing height, this may not allow you to place content below it. Regardless you could use javascript to get the height of the window then apply this to your image divs so they are the exact height in pixels....then stacking the divs should be no problem. In fact you could apply the same numbers to your absolute div layers and they'll all stack neatly.

Comment: Sorry for not clear description, guys. Already solved it. Vh measurement unit didn't have anything to do with this. I made a mistake by giving my hero image position absolute. It had to be position relative and then all the elements inside positioned relatively. Now that I changed properties vice verca, I can see new content under the main hero image not overlapping. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple items to clean up in the code, but to keep the images from overlapping you can remove both entries of position: absolute; from the .hero_img class.

After that, remove the padding left and right from all of the media queries of container-fluid.  This may affect and other padding that was needed in that container but would be a quick path to do what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah, I already removed position absolute and changed it to relative and it worked like I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index property to the navbar and give it a greater number value, the overlap will be removed.